# How to count the mutable array objects in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am fresher to iOS. In my application i have 3 mutable arrays with objects like

```
NSMutableArray   *MuteItem = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"a", @"b", @"b", @"c", @"c", @"c", nil]];
NSMutableArray   *MuteQuantity = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1", @"1", @"1", @"1", @"1", @"1", nil]];
NSMutableArray   *MutePrice = [NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"4", @"3", @"3", @"6", @"6", @"6", nil]];
```

Now i need to print that 3 mutable arrays values with counting the same item's quantity and calculate the price also like objects

```
MuteItem = { a, b, c }
MuteQuantity = { 1, 2, 3 }     // counting of same item's quantity like {1, 1+1, 1+1+1}
MutePrice = { 4, 6, 18 }      // here addition of same item's prices like {4, 3+3, 6+6+6}
```

So anybody, would you please help me in this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: simply use [array_Name count] to get the no obeject in array

Comment: and what is you second queston it not clear you want to calculate totall of price in mutPrice or what?

Comment: @kamaleshkumaryadav : In second question, in MuteItem, reduces the duplicated 'c' from 3 to 1 and duplicated 'b' from 2 to 1. In MuteQuantity, add the duplicated items quantity like we have two 'b' items so 1+1 quantity is 2 and three 'c' items so 1+1+1 quantity is 3. At the same time Prices also in MutePrice same like we have  two 'b' items so price is 3 + 3 = 6 and item 'c' price is 6+6+6 = 18. i think u understand the issue now.

Comment: @Ramesh please rewrite your question. I can vaguely understand what your trying to say and it is incredibly unclear. It also doesn't help that your comment on line 2 in the second code block makes it look like your are trying to recursively add its own contents, which I don't think you are trying to do. I would also point out it seems like your issue is only going to be solved by going through each array and working it out. These are uncommon actions to perform, there are no inbuilt methods for these

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin While his wording was not crystal clear I was able to answer his question with valid code below. He did say it was working, though for some reason he didn't accept the actual answer. I also can't figure out why someone downvoted me! LoL ;(

Comment: @Eidola I do have a hatred of people who downvote without commenting. On questions its generally clear if they've left no code or something but when its an answer that solves the question I really hate that. However while you may have been able to understand it, many downvoted so others see issue too. Also this is a very basic question that has shown no effort to solve it himself. Without any knowledge of objective-c it could be done badly with a few for loops. Asker made no attempt to learn, research or do anything other than to ask someone to do it for them. Very poor question

Comment: I do agree, it is a poorly asked question, I honestly only answered it as a mental exercise for myself and because I love all the new block functionality Apple has been adding to the API! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This code will do exactly as you requested, and will even handle any keys in MuteItem, and will generate three new arrays with the aggregate information from each of the three original arrays.

```
NSMutableArray* muteItem = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"a", @"b", @"b", @"c", @"c", @"c", nil];
NSMutableArray* muteQuantity = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1", @"1", @"1", @"1", @"1", @"1", nil];
NSMutableArray* mutePrice = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"4", @"3", @"3", @"6", @"6", @"6", nil];

NSMutableArray* setItem = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* setQuantity = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableArray* setPrice = [NSMutableArray array];

NSSet* itemSet = [NSSet setWithArray: muteItem];
for (NSString* key in itemSet) {
    NSIndexSet* indices = [muteItem indexesOfObjectsPassingTest: ^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [obj isEqualToString: key];
    }];

    __block NSInteger totalQuantity = 0;
    __block NSInteger totalPrice = 0;
    [indices enumerateIndexesUsingBlock: ^void(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        totalQuantity += [[muteQuantity objectAtIndex: idx] integerValue];
        totalPrice += [[mutePrice objectAtIndex: idx] integerValue];
    }];

    [setItem addObject: key];
    [setQuantity addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalQuantity]];
    [setPrice addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: totalPrice]];
}
```

NOTE: This code assumes you are using ARC. Also, in your original code you forgot to `nil` terminate your array constructors.

EDIT: I notice that your prices are integers, you may want to change them to floats if your currency uses decimal fractions. This would require changing the definition of `totalPrice` to `float` and you would want to change the end of the `totalPrice +=` line from `integerValue` to `floatValue`.

EDIT2: Renamed all variables that started with a capital letter as this violates standard naming convention. Only class names should begin with a capital letter, variables should always begin with lowercase, or an `_` for instance variables. :)

Comment: Glad to been of assistance! :)

Comment: You should accept answers that solve your questions, by the way! ;)

Comment: I'll vote you back up since the downvoter didn't bother to explain it and at quick glance I see no issue with this

Comment: Well thank you very much! :) I wonder if the downvoter was someone who got upset on a different question earlier about being downvoted (not even by me initially) for posting an off-topic question that belonged on a totally different site. Ah well, such is life on community moderated sites! :D

Comment: @Eidola, i did'nt down vote you, becz what u did is correct i may miss last past making all results to array, i used basic for loops so that he can get some idea, so after your post i got down vote thats wy i deleted my answer, though i did'nt even bother about this question, if you think its me the who down voted you, sorry i am not please dont include me in this...and also wy do you think i am upset, there are lot of questions in this site .... ;)

Comment: @Shan Oh, no I didn't mean you AT ALL. I was talking about someone else on a totally different question altogether! Sorry for any confusion! :)